# String compare C# - whole word match

Tags: c#

I have two strings:

```
string1  = "theater is small"; 
string2 =  "The small thing in the world";
```

I need to check weather the string "the" is present in the strings or not.
I can use the contains function, but can it do a whole word  match? i.e it should not match with "theater" of string1!

Answer (score 71):

The simplest solution is to use regular expressions and the word boundary delimiter `\b`:

```
bool result = Regex.IsMatch(text, "\\bthe\\b");
```

or, if you want to find mismatching capitalisation,

```
bool result = Regex.IsMatch(text, "\\bthe\\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

(`using System.Text.RegularExpressons`.)

Alternatively, you can split your text into individual words and search the resulting array. However, this isn’t always trivial because it’s not enough to split on white spaces; this would ignore all punctuation and yield wrong results. A solution is to once again use regular expressions, namely `Regex.Split`.

Comment: You might also want to specify RegexOptions.IgnoreCase

Comment: Your parameters are backwards! The input comes first, then the pattern to match.

Comment: it is passing "The small thing in the-world" also but my requirement is it should be return false.

Comment: There's a typo in the answer for the using directive-namespace. It's `System.Text.RegularExpressions`

Answer (score 14):

Use the method [Regex.IsMatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s19z3syh.aspx) using `\bthe\b`, `\b` represents a word boundary delimiter.

```
// false
bool string1Matched = Regex.IsMatch(string1, @"\bthe\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 

// true
bool string2Matched = Regex.IsMatch(string2, @"\bthe\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
str.Split().Contains(word);
```

or

```
char[] separators = { '\n', ',', '.', ' ' };    // add your own
str.Split(separators).Contains(word);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the answers here i made this extension method that finds multiple words in a text, returns the amount of words found, and ignores case matching.

```
public static int Search(this String text, params string[] pValores)
{
    int _ret = 0;
    try
    {
        var Palabras = text.Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', '?', ',', '!', '-', '(', ')', '"', '\''  }, 
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (string word in Palabras)
        {
            foreach (string palabra in pValores)
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(word, string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", palabra), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                {
                    _ret++;
                }
            }
        }               
    }
    catch { }
    return _ret;
}
```

Usage:

```
string Text = @"'Oh, you can't help that,' (said the Cat) 'we're all mad here. I'm MAD. ""You"" are mad.'";
int matches = Text.Search("cat", "mad"); //<- Returns 4
```

It's not perfect but it works.

Answer (score -1):

you can if you add the space in the word that you examine

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: that will often work but not if, for example, you search the string for "the " and the string *ends* with "the" as in: "this won't find the"

Comment: @aldanux sorry but this *is* an answer to the question, just not a very good one and also a very late one...

Answer (score -2):

You could use a regular expression instead. That way you can specify that you only want space or end of line in the end.