# How to display a string

Tags: c#, string, while-loop, io

I am working on a small code that searches an input text file (of my choice). I am creating a search function. So far I got it to display how many times the search word occurs in the text file and also the line number. I need some help on displaying how the searched word appears in the text file. For example, If I search for the word "the" and it appears as "THE" or "The" in the text file, I would want to display that on my console window.

Any help, advice, or suggestion is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Here is my code:

```
string line;
int counter = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Enter a word to search for: ");
string userText = Console.ReadLine();

string file = "NewTextFile.txt";
StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(file);

int found = 0;

while ((line = myFile.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    counter++;
    if (line.Contains(userText))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found on line number: {0}", counter);
        found++;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("A total of {0} occurences found", found);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use IndexOf instead of Contains since you want to do case-insensitive search:

```
if (line.IndexOf(userText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found on line number: {0}", counter);
    found++;
}
```

Comment: very nice! This will help as well.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
While ((line = myFile.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    line = line.toUpper();
    counter++;
    if (line.Contains(userText.toUpper()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found on line number: {0}", counter);
        Console.WriteLine(line.SubString(line.IndexOf(userText),userText.Length));
        found++;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("A total of {0} occurences found", found);
```

The line which is added here is

```
line.SubString(line.IndexOf(userText),userText.Length)
```

It means we need to find a `SubString` inside the `line` starting from the `index of` the first occurence of `userText` and the till the length of `userText length`

and if you wanted to only compare the string and show the original string you can use this code

```
While ((line = myFile.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string linecmp = line.toUpper();
    counter++;
    if (linecmp.Contains(userText.toUpper()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found on line number: {0}", counter);
        Console.WriteLine(line.SubString(line.IndexOf(userText),userText.Length));
        found++;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("A total of {0} occurences found", found);
```

Comment: This works! Now, I need to integrate the case-insensitivity. Thank you.

Comment: Added `toUpper()` to both the side to make it case insensitive.

Comment: I'm running into a problem. Say I search for the word "the", it is finding it in the word "their" as well. How do I bypass this problem?

Comment: So, I added toUpper() and it said start index cannot be less than zero.

Comment: you can have a look on [String compare C# - whole word match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904645/string-compare-c-sharp-whole-word-match) to bypass `the` and `their` problem

Comment: Is there a way to make it so that the user's input is case insensitive?

Comment: you can have a look on [Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring)

Comment: Wouldn't this line of code ignore the case of the user input: if (line.IndexOf(userText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)

Answer (score 0):

I have slightly modified your search function to resolve the issue you had before. As you mentioned in the comment, you said it is matching word 'THEIR' with word 'THE'.

Add the following code to resolve the mismatches issue.

```
string userText = Console.ReadLine() + " ";
```

Modified Full code below.

```
string line;
int counter = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Enter a word to search for: ");
string userText = Console.ReadLine() + " ";

string file = "NewTextFile.txt";
StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(file);

int found = 0;

while((line = myFile.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    line = line.ToUpper();
    counter++;
    if (line.Contains(userText.ToUpper()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found on line number: {0}", counter);
        Console.WriteLine(line.Substring(line.IndexOf(userText)+1,userText.Length));
        found++;
    }
 }

 Console.WriteLine("A total of {0} occurences found", found);
 Console.ReadLine();
```

Hope this helps you.