# Is there a way to compare the exact value of a string in C#

Tags: c#, string

So I made a simple c# file reader because I was bored and added an if statement to filter the results. But when I ran it, it gave me more results than I wanted. I was supposed to get
`276, 2`, and there was only one line inside the file with that value, but I got multiple. I checked the file and it had lines ending with the same value. I tried `string.Equals(line, "276, 2")` but it gave me the same results. I doubt there isn't something in c# that doesn't solve this issue.

Comment: Coud you please share the a [mre] (code and data)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use Regex, as it's mentioned in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904645/string-compare-c-sharp-whole-word-match)

```
bool result = Regex.IsMatch(line, "\\b276, 2\\b");
```

Comment: Why would that be better than `string.Equals`?